# Angular 7 - [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience

Tags: angular

All,

I am running on an Apple MacBook Pro running OS X El Capitan v.10.11.6.

I know this question has been asked many times over.  I have read them all, carefully, assessing the responses and ever-refined my code in an attempt to isolate the issue.  I have refined this to the point where I:

1. Erased my hard drive,
2. Installed Node, downloading the latest package: node-v10.15.3.pkg,
3. Installed Angular: "npm install -g @angular/cli" (v.7.3.6),
4. Created a directory and a new Angular project with routing and scss styling: "ng new AngularTest"
5. Performed "ng serve" to ensure the Angular template project runs, checking http://localhost:4200 in Chrome for confirmation (everything is fine),
6. Performed "ng test".

I made no changes to any of the files that are created throughout the process described above - pure vanilla.

The "ng test" results in 3 successfully executed tests, Chrome opens and I see the goodness I expect.  However, when I look at the JavaScript Console, I see the error!

Is this inherent in Angular 7.3.6?  I am experiencing other issues in my Angular project but don't feel comfortable focusing on the resolution of these subsequent issues if I cannot resolve this issue, which is the first one showing up in the Console window (cause and effect?).  Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Please see the included screen prints and package.json file.

[The Tests Are Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DA9ba.png)

[image]

[Oops, There Is An Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rY6z1.png)

[image]

Package.json file

```js
{
  "name": "test-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: You should learn to tell the difference between an error and a warning. What you see in the console is a warning. Nothing to be alarmed about. I get the same thing every time I run unit tests, too. It isn't something can, or need to fix.

Comment: R.Richards - Thank you for pointing out this difference.  I appreciate it.  It is odd, though, that a brand new project straight from the box would have such a warning.  That said, the most important aspect of this is that is not have an impact on the execution of my code, of my tests, to be more specific.

Thank you for taking time to review my question.

Comment: Brand new projects built should not have warnings if possible, and tgibbons is right to have concerns about it. I think R. Richards' comment is a bit rude and condescending. If nothing else, it takes time for a developer to look up the warning and figure out if it is something to be concerned about. Looks like Angular is tracking this here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31676

Comment: @LocalPCGuy - Thank you.  I had not seen this response.  I appreciate the input.  This helps, a lot.